# Makefile: How to get wildcard (!arch)/*.c

Tags: bash, makefile, extglob

I'm trying to make a makefile for compiling all the source files in my project, wich are spread in several directories like this:

```
libc/
  arch/
  include/
  math/
  stdio/
```

And i want to exclude all the files from the arch and include directories, I can do this in the shell using the command ls !(arch)/*.c
But when i try to do the same using

> $(wildcard !(arch)/*.c)

it doesn't work.
How can i make it work in my makefile? Can i use something like !(arch || include) to exclude both directories?

Comment: have you tried backslashing the inner parenthesis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> $(wildcard !(arch)/*.c)
> ```
>
> it doesn't work. How can i make it work in my makefile? Can i use
>   something like !(arch || include) to exclude both directories?

Assuming you're asking about GNU Make, the answer to both questions is no.

[The syntax](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Wildcards.html#Wildcards) of built-in wildcards in GNU Make is pretty basic:

> The wildcard characters in make are `‘*’`, `‘?’` and `‘[…]’`, the same as in
>   the Bourne shell.

You can use [built-in functions](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/make/manual/html_node/Functions.html#Functions) for this kind of task:

```
$(wildcard $(addsuffix *.c,$(filter-out arch/,$(wildcard */))))
$(wildcard $(addsuffix *.c,$(filter-out arch/ include/,$(wildcard */))))
```

Or just shell out to `find`:

```
$(shell find -name "*.c" -a \! -path "./arch/*" -a \! -path "./include/*")

# This one is a bit more efficient:
$(shell find \( -path "./arch" -prune -o -path "./include" -prune -o -name "*.c" \) -a -type f)
```